# Python: How to remove duplicate values for one key inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dictionary with duplicate values for one key. How could I remove the duplicates?

Initial dictionary:

```py
dict = {"a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1], "b": [4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5]}
```

Desired dictionary:

```py
dict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 2, 1, 6]}
```

Comment: Don't use dict as a name, it shadows the built-in `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Solution 1: If you have control over the data while its being constructed, then store the data in a set instead as a list

2- Solution 2: If data is coming from api or database then you can process the data in the following way:

```
dictionary = {"a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1], "b": [4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5]}
for each_key, value in dictionary.items():
   dictionary[each_key] = list(set(value))
```

Note: You lose the order of your lists.
Also, you should not keep your variable name as `dict` as its a python keyword

Answer (score 4):

Use dictionary comprehension to build a new dictionary, eliminating duplicates through the use of `set`:

```py
dict = {"a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1], "b": [4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5]}
dict = { key : list(set(value)) for key, value in dict.items()}
```

Converting a `list` to a `set` removes duplicates. We then convert it back to a `list`. Note that it doesn't necessarily preserve the original order of items in each list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use set instead of list internally.

If list is the only thing you want to use then do this,

```
myDict = dict({"a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1], "b": [4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5]})

for key,listOfDup in myDict.items():
    myDict[key] = list(set(listOfDup))
```

Comment: why the double call to `set()`?

Comment: oops, that was a typo. Thanks, it's edited now.